# noMethodError in Property#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having a bit of an issue to find where this error is coming from.

I am getting this error:

[image]

I am not sure, it the issue has to do with the naming of my folder in views, I named it property ... instead of properties (I already tried changing it but I still get an error)

[image]

This is what my Model looks like

```
class Property < ApplicationRecord
  validates :address, presence: true, length: {minimum: 10}
  validates :price, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true
  validates :bedrooms, presence: true
  validates :bathrooms, presence: true
  validates :type, presence: true
  validates :sqft, presence: true
  validates :lot, presence: true
  validates :year_built, presence: true
 end
```

and this is my controller:

property_controller.rb

```
class PropertyController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @properties = Property.all
  end

  def new
    @property = Property.new
  end

  def create
    @property = Property.new(property_params)
    if @property.save?
      flash[:notice] = 'Property was successufully created.'
      redirect_to property_path(@property)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private
  def property_params
    params.require(:property).permit(:address, :price, :description, 
:bedrooms, :bathrooms, :type, :sqft, :lot, :year_built)
  end
end
```

and my view file

```
_form.html.erb
     <% if @property.errors.any? %>
       <h3>The following errors prevented the addition of this property.
      </h3>
      <ul>


    <% @property.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    <% end %>

    <%= form_for @property do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.text_field :address, required: true, placeholder: "Address", 
    class: "form-control"%>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.text_field :price, required: true, placeholder: "Price", 
    class: "form-control"%>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.text_area :description, required: true, placeholder: 
    "Description", class: "form-control"%>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-success" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

new.html.erb

    <h3>Add new Property:</h3>

    <%#= render 'form' %>
```

It seems that the error is with the form, because if I comment the form out, the new.html.erb displays fine. Any help would be appreciated it.

rake routes | grep property

[image]

Comment: could you please add `rake routes | grep property`?

Comment: sure, I added an image above, because it was too long for an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare a `form_for` without explicitly defining the `url`, Rails will guess what route you are wanting. In your case, since `@property` is a new instance (unpersisted), Rails wants to `POST` to the `properties_path`. This is simply Rails convention.

Your most likely solution is just to add `resources :properties` to your `routes.rb` file. If you paste your file we can give you a bit more information as to why this is necessary.

**UPDATE**

Rails expects table names (and therefore routes) to be the pluralized version of your model name. So your `Property` model has a `properties` table and route. Using `resources :properties` (plural) follows Rails conventions and let's everything work together nicely.

Comment: Hey XML, I do have it set on my routes.rb          Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  
  resources :welcome
  root 'welcome#index'

  resources :property
end

Comment: Change `resources :property` to `resources :properties`

Comment: that just seem to give me a whole new set of errors... No route matches [GET] "/property/new" ... I am assuming that I would have to change links and what not. I might try it.

Comment: Yes that's correct. All of your URLs will now be pluralized, but you'll be following Rails convention so your life will be easier from this point forward.